# Qt/C++ Elegant way for comparison based signal dispatching

Tags: c++, qt, signals

I am working on a project where I receive a message via UDP and based on that message I am emitting different signals and all of them have the same parameters.

The structure is like this:

```
if(command_type == COMMAND_TYPE_MOVE)
{
    emit sigMoveForward(data);
}
else if(command_type == COMMAND_TYPE_STOP)
{
    emit sigStopMove(data);
}
```

This gets really tedious to programm and maintain when getting past like 10 commands. Is there a way to do this better?

I thought of creating a QMap and doing a lookup on it and emiting the signal I am getting. Is this possible in Qt to have a pointer to the function and omit it this way?

Comment: Maybe is the command pattern what you're looking for? If you are allowed to don't use just int or string for command but incapsulate them in a class. Signals are just functions so you can store a pointer to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between

```
emit sigMoveForward(data);
```

and

```
sigMoveForward(data);
```

So, you can create QMap with pointers to signals or beter plain array if commands are continuous. It has quite tricky syntax, though.

```
void (Your_class::*signals[COMMAND_COUNT])(your_data_type) ;
...
signals[COMMAND_TYPE_MOVE] = &Your_class::moveForward;
signals[COMMAND_TYPE_STOP] = &Your_class::stopMove;
....
```

And emit it like that:

```
(this->*signals[command_type])(data);
```

Comment: This was exactly what I am looking for, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If all signals contain the same `data`, you could send a unique signal containing 2 parameters (the `command_type` + the `data`) and then check the `command_type` in the receiving slot

```cpp
//...
emit sigCommand(command_type, data)
//...

void MyClass::commandReceived(CommandType command_type, QVariant data) {
    if(command_type == COMMAND_TYPE_MOVE)
    {
        moveForward(data);
    }
    else if(command_type == COMMAND_TYPE_STOP)
    {
        stopMove(data);
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Its not about where I do the comparison, its about shrinking down on the amount of comparisons I have to write. Also the signals might have different connections to different objects

Comment: @Curunir But then if you have 15 different commands you still have to declare the 15 different signals in your header right? I am not sure looking up a function pointer in a QMap would be much more efficient than checking the command_type in a switch for example and emitting the right signal accordingly (like you are doing now).

Comment: This is not a solution, you're moving the problem from the sender to the receiver